# Java, Scanner only reads the first two lines and ignores the rest

Tags: java, while-loop, text-files, java.util.scanner

So I have created a part of my program where it's supposed to read from a text-file. Problem is it only reads the first two lines(flawlessly)and when it loops a second time `tempLine` is "". And because of this I am getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Why is this happening?

For each person there are 2 lines. These are added to a list.

File looks like this:

```
7603021234, Alhambra Aromes
2018-07-01
8104021234, Bear Belle
2018-12-02
8512021234, Chamade Coriola 
2017-03-12
7608021234, Diamanda Djedi
2019-01-30
7605021234, Elmer Ekorrsson
2010-04-07
7911061234, Fritjoff Flacon
1999-12-16
1111111111, Greger Ganache
2019-03-23
5711121234, Hilmer Heur
2019-08-18
2222222222, Ida Idylle
2017-03-07
1212121212, Jicky Juul
2018-09-27
4604151234, Kadine Karlsson
2018-01-09
9110261234, Liu Lingren
2018-02-15
7907281234, Mitsuko Mayotte
2018-12-22
7805211234, Nahema Ninsson
2019-01-04
```

and this is my source-code:

```
   public class ReadFile {

    private List<Customer> allMembers = new LinkedList<>();

    public void readFile () throws IOException {

        String tempLine;
        String[] tempString;
        String personalNumber;
        String firstName;
        String lastName;
        LocalDate lastPayed;

        Path inFilePath = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Allan\\Documents\\Nackademin\\OOP\\Inlämningsuppgift2\\customers.txt");
        Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(inFilePath);

        while(fileScanner.hasNext()) {
            tempLine = fileScanner.nextLine();
            tempString = tempLine.split(" ");
            personalNumber = tempString[0].replace(",", "");
            firstName = tempString[1];
            lastName = tempString[2];

            if (fileScanner.hasNext()) {
                lastPayed = LocalDate.parse(fileScanner.next());
                allMembers.add(new Customer(personalNumber, firstName, lastName, lastPayed));
            }

        }
    }

    public List<Customer> getAllMembers() {
        return allMembers;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try changing to `lastPayed = LocalDate.parse(fileScanner.nextLine());`

Comment: It worked! But why???

Comment: I believe `next()` leaves the newline in the scanner's input buffer but `nextLine()` consumes it. So in the 2nd iteration `tempLine = fileScanner.nextLine();` is reading the newline at the end of the 2nd line and returning an empty string.

Comment: See: [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](//stackoverflow.com/q/13102045)

Answer (score 0):

Please use nextLine() instead on next().

```
while(fileScanner.hasNextLine()) {
            tempLine = fileScanner.nextLine();
            tempString = tempLine.split(" ");
            personalNumber = tempString[0].replace(",", "");
            firstName = tempString[1];
            lastName = tempString[2];

            if (fileScanner.hasNextLine()) {
                lastPayed = LocalDate.parse(fileScanner.nextLine());
                allMembers.add(new Customer(personalNumber, firstName, lastName, lastPayed));
            }

        }
```